# Error: class to INSERT content into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have recently began to use OOP in PHP and I am starting with functions which I am fairly familiar with. I have been working on a data-management system connected with MySQL database. I am running into issues when it comes to inserting content into the Database and getting this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables ... on line 140
```

This is my code:

```
public function create_val( $content_array, $table )
{
    $array_num = count($content_array);

    // create value holders
    $value_param = str_repeat( '?, ', $array_num );
    $stmt_values = rtrim($value_param, ', ');

    // create bind params
    $stmt_param = str_repeat('s', $array_num);


    foreach($content_array as $key => $value)
    {
        $key_val[] = $key;
        $val[] = $value;
    }

    $table_rows = implode(', ', $key_val);
    $insert_val = implode(', ', $val);

    $sql = "INSERT " . $table . " (" . $table_rows . ") VALUES (" . $stmt_values . ")";

    if($stmt = $this->_connection->prepare( $sql ))
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt->bind_param($stmt_param, $insert_val);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo "There was an unexpected problem. " . $e->getMessages();
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the error is being caused by this line: `$stmt->bind_param($stmt_param, $insert_val);`.

But I just do not understand why; I have checked both the `$stmt_param` and `$insert_val` and they match in number - in this specific attempt which I am running.

The values are being inserted as a `$key => $value` pairs. This is my setup to call the class:

```
$array = array(
    'column1' => 'an item',
    'column2' => 'a second content',
    'column3' => 'some information',
    'column4' => 'what what what???'
);
$db->create_val($array, 'table_name');
```

My goal with this function is to be as reusable and modular as I possibly can code it. I have looked at many similar questions but have not found any I can use. Even when it came to classes, they were not really reusable for different purposes, and my purpose is to be reusable.

Comment: 1.check the table columns and 2.compare with what you are sending and 3.echo the `$sql` query and 4.try to execute in database and 5.tell what error you get.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed my test database has 4 columns, all `varchar(500)` I am not sure the query has much to do with the actual conflict.

Comment: `bind_param` is only good for binding a single parameter at a time.

Comment: @Scuzzy I understand, but I am only attempting to insert 1 record in the database at a time, and it works just fine if I was to write `$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $item1, $item2, $item3, $item4);`

Comment: Then you might need to use call_user_func_array to inject an array of parameters, or throw your array into the pdo->execute($array) functions parameter

Comment: How could I go about that? I have never actually used `call_user_func_array`

Comment: First try with http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php especially Example #3, first you want your SQL to be a template with your `?` placeholders, then execute function can inject your array values in that order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152933/discussion-between-scuzzy-and-samuel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of PHP 5.6 you can call the `bind_param` function with the [unpacking operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat), which allows you to call it directly (and without using `call_user_func_array`), just change this line...

```
$stmt->bind_param($stmt_param, ...$val);
```